# How to add multiple service references in single proxy class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf

I have a WCF service solution which has 5 service references which is part of a particular group.

e.g. A component names ABC exposes five services P, Q, R, S & T.

Now if I go with tradition way i.e. right click-> Add service reference, this will create 5 different proxy classes for P, Q, R, S & T.

What I want to achieve is single proxy class names `ABCProxy` and have all the operations from  P, Q, R, S & T into it so it will be easy for me in development.

I tries using svcutil but could not figure out how to group them all.

Comment: Probably not a good idea.   What happens if your remote services have different security models?  Not to mention you are breaking SOA best practices

Comment: You might implement multiple clientbase<T>, service contract interfaces. this ought to be a complex task since the clientbase<T> interface only has one communication channel which depends on the service endpoint address. we have to instance the specific class manually according to the service endpoint address. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.clientbase-1?view=netframework-4.7.2 Moreover, we could also use the ChannelFactory<T> interface to create a unique channel.https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-the-channelfactory